# Cosa vuol dire "far solette" in questo testo?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *La malora*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> Ma con tutta la sua grazia bisognava vederla sul lavoro e il sollievo che dava alla padrona, la quale aveva fatto presto la pace con Tobia che gliel’aveva trovata e presa. E quando uno credeva che avesse finito di far tutto, lei si metteva alla finestra all’ultimo chiaro e ci dava dentro a **far solette**, non si possono contare le **solette che ci ha fatto**.

Ho cercato il vocabolo "soletta" in alcuni dizionari, ma non sono sicura di aver capito il senso dell'espressione "far solette" che appare nel brano sopra citato. Significa che questa ragazza si metteva a rammendare la parte inferiore dei calzini?

Comment: Le solette sono degli inserti che venivano messi dentro la scarpa tra il piede e la suola interna. In passato le stesse scarpe venivano usate per ogni tipo di lavoro e le solette erano anche un modo per salvaguardare il piede.

Comment: Quindi si tratta dell'accezione 1.c del [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/soletta)? Non so perché avevo pensato che fosse la 1.a. Se vuoi puoi scriverlo come risposta.

Comment: Ho verificato sul campo chiedendo a conoscenti più anziani che vivevano in basso Piemonte e mi hanno detto che per solette intendevano sia il rinforzo della parte sottostante dei calzettoni contro l’usura, che uno strato fatto di panno da inserire tra calza e suola utilizzato nei mesi invernali per tenere al caldo i piedi. Quindi nel testo l’autore potrebbe intendere entrambe le cose.

Comment: @abarisone: Bene! Potresti metterlo come risposta?

Answer (score 1):

Ho verificato sul campo chiedendo a conoscenti più anziani che vivevano in basso Piemonte e mi hanno detto che per solette intendevano sia il rinforzo della parte sottostante dei calzettoni contro l’usura, che uno strato fatto di panno da inserire tra calza e suola utilizzato nei mesi invernali per tenere al caldo i piedi.

Quindi nel testo l’autore potrebbe intendere entrambe le cose.

In un [dizionario di Piemontese](http://alessandrialisondria.altervista.org/dialet-lissandren-dizionario-alessandrino-italiano/) ho trovato questi due termini distinti che vengono tradotti in Italiano facendo riferimento ai due possibili significati di soletta:

> scapén (s. m.). **soletta** delle calze. # an scapèn = senza scarpe.

e

> sutpé (s. m.). sottopiede, **soletta**, cuoio sottile che si sovrappone
>   alla suola della scarpa internamente quando questa non ha anima, e che
>   poi si ricopre ancora col soppanno.